# Why not have a resource sharing section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why not have a resource sharing section?

For example: The other day I read a really good paper on weaknesses in SSL/TLS and in the Certificate Authority/Browser infrastructure, and I'd think it be cool to share it with others.

I think having a dedicated section with no questions, just posting good reads/papers, educational videos or learning resources would be useful especially for beginners looking for good learning resources. (excluding direct product promotion).

So the question is, why not?

Comment: I like the idea, though  I'd rather have it as a "news" section to help us stay on top of things.

Comment: Well, SE is a Q&A site after all. There are many platforms where it's possible to share resources like [/r/netsec](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/), etc.

Comment: I agree completely with Arminius and Rory. Although the idea seems useful, we would then be deviating from the main idea of SE, and would essentially have a conglomerate of SE and reddit. No reason to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you posted items like that in chat, most folks would welcome it. If it's good enough people may star it so it stays in the sidebar in chat.

Stack Exchange is not a site for sharing links to useful news articles. It is almost the opposite, really, focusing on providing information **here**.

As Arminius commented, there is already a plethora of places online for that sort of thing...we don't need another.

Answer (score 1):

Questions regarding lists of resources have been raised on several of the SE meta sites.  Most of which are inconclusive as to whether to create such a list.

There is a good response from the SE staff regarding such lists [here on Latin.SE](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/142).  This essentially says that these lists should not be on the meta sites - if they are allowed to exist at all.

There is a successful community wiki resources list on the meta of English Language Learners - [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/4376).  However, that is not providing links to news articles but to stable reference sources.

I would suggest that a list of news articles or papers is not a good idea.  However, a *good* list of learning resources *may* be workable.